# factory_girl not playing nicely with rspec2 - ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Am using Rails 3.1.0rc8, Factory Girl 2.1.2, Factory Girl Rails 1.2.0, and RSpec 2.7.0.

I believe the error I am having is related to the problems discussed on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/daa24556d90c31fc).

I have a spec that looks like this:

**spec/integration/my_integration_spec.rb**:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'A Workflow' do
  before(:all) do
    @reseller = Factory(:reseller)
    @product = Factory(:product, :reseller => @reseller)
  end

  describe 'A feature' do
    it 'Does something' do
    end

    describe 'A sub-feature' do
      before(:all) do
        # Error!
        @product.sold_at << Factory(:outlet, :reseller => @reseller)
      end

      it 'Does something' do
      end
    end
  end
```

Running this spec causes an exception in the sub-feature:

```
Failure/Error: @product.sold_at << Factory(:outlet, :reseller => @reseller)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
  Reseller(#90828680) expected, got Reseller(#59351220)
```

Interestingly, this error does *not* occur when I move the content of the nested before-hook into the primary before-hook.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'A Workflow' do
  before(:all) do
    @reseller = Factory(:reseller)
    @product = Factory(:product, :reseller => @reseller)

    # No error!
    @product.sold_at << Factory(:outlet, :reseller => @reseller)
  end

  describe 'A feature' do
    it 'Does something' do
    end

    describe 'A sub-feature' do
      it 'Does something' do
      end
    end
  end
```

Would really appreciate any help in understanding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `before(:all)` in each spec file.  Use `before(:all) at the top of a spec and then`before(:each)`in a describe block. This is the reason that your second example works, you have removed the second`before(:all)`.

Also, be careful with `before(:all)`. Any data created here will not be deleted from the database at the end of a spec, you will need to delete it in an `after(:all)` or use the database cleaner gem. See [link](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/issues/2) for reasoning.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about the restriction to one `before(:all)` per spec file. The documentation for RSpec2 (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) has an example of nested `before(:each)` just as I have in the original post.

Comment: Please recheck your original post. You have two before(:all) statements and no before(:each). If this is the way you have your actual code then I don't think it's going to work.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "I don't think it's going to work"? I've created a gist (https://gist.github.com/1439749) demonstrating the use of nested `before(:all)` blocks. It works fine, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Apologies - I've gone back and reviewed my understanding and the nested before(:all) is supposed to work like you have it set up.  It's worth noting that it's not recommended - see this [question with a response from David Chelimsky][http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/584047]. I've had another look at your code - can you try `@product.sold_at << FactoryGirl.build(:outlet, :product => @product, :reseller => @reseller)